# Image doesn't display in SpannableString with Image

Tags: android, spannablestring

```
import static android.text.TextUtils.join;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ImageSpan;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List; 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView testText;
TextView testText2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    testText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    testText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

    List<SpannableString> refinements = new ArrayList<>();
    refinements.add(getFilterWithIcon("100", R.drawable.ic_feature_bed_s));
    refinements.add(new SpannableString("Testing text"));

    //Text without icon
    testText.setText(join(" | ", refinements));
    //Text with icon 
    testText2.setText(getFilterWithIcon("100", R.drawable.ic_feature_bed_s));

}

private SpannableString getFilterWithIcon(String stringValue, int icon) {
    Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), icon);
    image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    String spString = "  " + stringValue;
    SpannableString spFilterWithIcon = new SpannableString(spString);
    spFilterWithIcon.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return spFilterWithIcon;
}}
```

[image: Result]

The image doesn't appear when joined with another SpannableString. It works only as a single SpannableString. 
However I need to join multiple SpannableStrings with & without images.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: where is join method?

Comment: @chandil03 it's from android TextUtils.

Comment: try using concate method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a SpannableStringBuilder to append multiple imagespan and text

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.append(edittext.getText());
builder.append(getFilterWithIcon("100", R.drawable.ic_feature_bed_s));
```

and finally set

```
editText.setText(builder);
```

Note though SpannableStringBuilder is an immutable class it can't be changed.

Comment: getFilterWithIcon were setSpan with index 0 -> 1, so your append method does not work